# Word に Redmine のチケットへのリンクを挿入しても、トップページが表示されてしまう

Tags: redmine, ms-word

Word文書中にハイパーリンクでredmineのチケットを指定したとき、ジャンブ先がredmineのトップページの表示止まりになってしまいます．
（例えば、`https://mng.example.jp/redmine/issues/100` など)

ハイパーリンクからredmineのチケットが表示されるようにするには、どういった対応が必要なのか、ご存知の方がおられましたらご教示ください．

Comment: Wordに貼らずにチケットのURLを直接ブラウザのアドレス欄に入れた場合はどうなりますか？ / 設定によってはRedmineにログインが必要なので、チケットを直接開くとログインを求められる場合がありますが、こちらはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．ブラウザに直接URLを入れた場合は問題なくチケットがオープンされます．その状態でブラウザを起動したまま、Wordのリンクをクリックした場合は、redmineのトップページの表示となってしまいます．